# Cannot create user as administrator in AWS Cognito

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

We have been trying to create users in our Cognito User Pool but keep getting a rather weird error. The stack trace looks as follows:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Not Found",
  "errorType": "UnknownError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
    "Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
    "Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
    "Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
    "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
    "/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"
  ]
}
```

Here's our code which is executed in Lambda. The Lambda function itself is invoked by API Gateway without proxy integration.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: "ap-south-1",
  endpoint: "https://dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
});

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const cispClient = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

const table = process.env.TABLE_NAME || "User_Info_Test";

exports.newDriverCreated = function (event, context) {

  console.log('event: ', event);

  // Get username, password
  const username = event.username;
  const password = event.password;

  // Get first and last name
  const firstName = event.name;
  const lastName = event.family_name;

  // Get phone number
  const phone = event.phone;

  const driverData = {
    "TemporaryPassword": password,
    "UserAttributes": [
      {
        "Name": "phone_number",
        "Value": phone,
      },
      {
        "Name": "first_name",
        "Value": firstName,
      },
      {
        "Name": "family_name",
        "Value": lastName,
      },
    ],
    "Username": username,
    "UserPoolId": 'user-pool-id',
    "ValidationData": [
      {
        "Name": "phone_number",
        "Value": phone
      }
    ]
  }

  cispClient.adminCreateUser(driverData, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('adminCreateUser error: ', err);
      context.done(err);
    } else {
      console.log('adminCreateUser data: ', data);
      context.done(null, data);
    }

  });

}
```

The error occurs when we call the `adminCreateUser()` function. We have absolutely no clue what could be going wrong as we are really new to AWS as a whole.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the role associated with this lambda?

Comment: are you trying to execute cognito in  'us-east-1' whereas your region is set to  "ap-south-1"

Answer (score 0):

Try mentioning the endpoint when creating the cispClient. It looks like it could be a problem due to an incorrect endpoint. See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Endpoint.html)  and [enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#endpoint-property). Look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cognito_identity_region) for a list of endpoints.